# action-on-google how to comfirm message when Browsing carousel is pressed

Tags: actions-on-google

As part of the results to a user in the Google Assistant, I'm presenting them with a Browsing Carousel. Currently, when they click on one of the results of the carousel, they are taken directly to the URL specified. This works correctly and is expected.

However, I would like to present them with a confirmation message or interstitial through the Assistant before they go to that URL. This is something like the warning pages you see on web sites reminding people they're going to an external site.

Is there any way to do this using the Assistant?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. The Browsing Carousel will take them directly to the URL specified. Although you have a few things you can do to work around this depending on the exact experience you want.

One solution is that the link-out can go to an interstitial page you control that asks if they want to continue to the target site. If they click "no", you can redirect back to the URL that will re-start the Action, while "yes" would continue to the site. (This also has the advantage that you can use traditional analytics for this method.)

Another solution is that you use a Carousel instead of a Browsing Carousel. When the user selects an option, you can present a card with a link-out for the destination site or another, similar, way to link out.